# Easy way to tell if a method is overriding another method?

Tags: objective-c

I'm just beginning with ObjC. I'm wondering how to find out when looking at code, written by me or from a template that comes when you use the wizard to create a new class, how you can tell if a method is overriding something.

In Java, you can mark a method with @Override, and then it's very easy to see if it's overriding something. That's not foolproof, because @Override is optional, but if I'm still unsure I can just type that in and see if it generates an error.

Is the only way to look up the source of the superclass, or in the case of a framework to read the documentation?

Comment: If you use Xcode, you could try to see if the editor tries to autocomplete the method signature when you type it.

Comment: You can use AppCode. That indicates (and allows navigation to) super- and subclass implementations of a method.

Comment: There is no such thing as a wizard.  That's a windows thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a way to see this immediately, but you could check if `super` responds
to the same selector. Example:

```
- (void)myMethod
{
    // Temporarily add this line. If the compiler does NOT complain,
    // "myMethod" overrides a method from some superclass.
    [super myMethod];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use instancesRespondToSelector to see if your instance has an implementation of the method in its object hierarchy.

```
[MyClass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(myMethod)];
```

or depending on what type of checking you need to do

```
[MyClassSuperClass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(myMethod)];
```